# Is it possible to delete LocalStorage while application is closed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, local-storage

Is it possible to delete a specific key within an application's LocalStorage without opening the app itself?

I was thinking of creating a batch file script for deleting a certain key within the app's LocalStorage while the application is still closed. The problem is accessing the application's LocalStorage outside of the app. So far, a NodeJS script seems plausible.

The application is a Vue app encapsulated in an Electron instance.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: You could think in another way that "how to handle localStorage when your app starts"

Comment: This is the solution that you are thinking of, can you please share what us the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @NikleshRaut doing the task when the app starts is not possible, since the idea is it must be cleared at any point in time, whether the app is running or not.

Comment: Ok try as nishant suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it on your `app.vue` using `beforeUnmount` hook

Here is a link to the VueJs lifeCycle hook List [Link](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html) in there you can find 2 hooks that you can possibly use `beforeUnmount` & `unmounted`

However as such kind of clean up activities are done in `beforeUnmount` and server-level such crash reports and other log activities are done `unmounted`